Jaspersoft fram is not reducing size when textfields inside are removed(remove line when blank)
[](https://i.sstatic.net/UmnAkMqE.png)
I have an issue where there is a white space between the grey frame and the frame selected in the image. This is due to some of the lines are removed when blank and seems like the fram cannot reduce size when this happens. Is there any way to get around this? the grey frame is position type float.
I have tried positioning the grey frame over the content from the selected fram in image but then it just overflows the addresses and does not get pushed down.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
